# Smallest OS that supports NTFS & FAT32 filesystems

Tags: windows, operating-system

Is there any OS that I can boot with a usb and then see whats inside the c drive and d local disk so that I can manipulate the files in 
I tested many Small Operating systems but I never saw files or drives like C:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can mount NTFS and FAT32 drives with Linux, you can manipulate Windows files after booting a small Linux distribution like PuppyLinux or any other.

I also just read that KolibriOS can read those file systems, and it is 1.44MB large, surely one of the smallest graphical OS.

Comment: I'll try KoilibriOS because it looks of my type and if it worked I'll accept your ans.

Comment: I'll try both actually.

Comment: Not sooo small but I think Slax.org worth a review. It's a robust, traditional and very stable "Linux to go". And he attends your demand.

Comment: Maybe other OS you already tried can read those drives, but you have to mount them manually.